# Is this a React prevState issue and how can I solve it?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is kind of complicated to explain.  I'm trying to make a toggle function that adds and deletes items on a different page with useContext. Everything adds and deletes fine until I tab to the other page, and that's where the error begins. Once I do that the function ignores what's in the array and will duplicate items in the array.  What's odd about it is if I console.log or manually check the new item with the current array items it shows me everything.  For example in order to add the new item to the array it checks if the index of new item is -1.  If it is it will add the item and if not it will delete the item.  However once I leave the page it doesn't see the item anymore and adds it anyway.  If I console.log the item name and new item name, I can see both, and if I use === to check it also works fine until I switch tabs and then even though it's still console logging both names somehow it's still adding the item and ignoring that it already contains the item.

The code directory in my sandbox is src/Helpers/MyPicsContext.  Here is the link to my sandbox [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-crypto-app-g2q8kv)

The tabs on the website are Picks and the search page which you can access on Picks before any items are added or by clicking the magnifying glass in the top right of page.

And here is the actual code for the context page.

```
export const MyPicksContextProvider = props => {
  const [picksList, setPicksList] = useState(
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('picksList'))
    || 
      []
  )
  
  //console.log(picksList)

   useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("picksList", JSON.stringify(picksList));
  }, [picksList]);

  const deleteCoin = coin => {
    if (picksList.length === 1) {
      setPicksList([]);
    } else {
      setPicksList(picksList.filter(list => {
        console.log(list)
        //console.log(coin)
        return list !== coin;
      }))
    }
    console.log('deleted');
    console.log(picksList)
  }  

  const toggleCoin = (coin) => {
    if (picksList.length === 0) {
      setPicksList([...picksList, coin]);
    } else {
      if (picksList.indexOf(coin) === -1 ) {
        setPicksList([...picksList, coin]);
        console.log('added 1')
      } else {
        deleteCoin(coin)
      }
    }
  }
```

Perhaps I just don't understand useState and prevState, but I can't seem to find any examples that apply to what I'm trying to do here.  It makes total sense in creating a counter or something simple like that.

Comment: I have tried using setPicksList(prevState => ...prevState, coin) and other examples I have seen but they all seem to break the code.  Perhaps the issue is iterating through prev state in order to set a new state, if prevState is even the issue.

Comment: Could you include the logic where picksList is provided as context? Or is it consumed via local storage on other pages?

Comment: I tried adding prevState there but then what ends up happening is local storage returns undefined and breaks the page.  But I also am not sure I did it correctly.  I also tried just removing local storage and it will always return undefined instead of the empty array.  So I went back to messing around with just the toggle function.

Comment: If it helps, local storage will only be used for storing the picks items.  Possibly also the coloring of the stars since I can't check if pickslist includes anything before it's initialized.  I've been trying to figure this out for a week and a half now so I haven't gotten that far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that .indexOf checks for referential equality of items, same as using `===`. This means that `const a = {id: 'x'}; const b = a; console.log(a === b);` will output true, but `const a = {id: 'x'}; const b = {id: 'x'}; console.log(a === b);` will output false.

In your situation, upon changing pages / refreshing, the state is reset and loaded from local storage. However, this creates new objects which are not referentially equal. Instead of using `.indexOf` you want to use `.find`, something like `array.find((element) => element.id === newItem.id)` to find the index of the item. You could also do your own deep equality check (confirming every field matches), but I suspect the ID alone is sufficient.

In fact, I would also recommend only keeping the array of "picks" as an array of string ID's. Then you can lookup the full data from your table for each of these ID's. Otherwise the current price will be stored in localStorage, and could be out of date.

Comment: Let me try that now

Comment: Wow that actually works,  but then the issue becomes it won't delete from the local storage items.  I tried also adding .find to the deleteCoin function and chaining .filter to that but it does nothing.

Comment: Also if you have any suggestions as to how I could incorporate coloring the stars based on what's included in picks list so it colors the star in when you add the item into picks list and uncolors it when you click to delete, I know I'm going to run into similar problems there.

Comment: The delete function similarly needs to be updated to check `return list.id !== coin.id;` rather than `return list !== coin;`

Comment: For coloring stars, I would recommend just using your context and checking if it includes one with a matching ID. For example, `const { items } = useContext(MyContext); const isChecked = items.findIndex((item) => item.id === props.id) >= 0`